# page returns to root when make any operation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

I have an asp .net web site which contains "masterpage". my project worked perfectly. i made some changes on my "masterpage" (it is "onmouseover menu" which has a "javascript" and "ajax"). now any other page is working without problem. but i have one page which returns me to the root of the website automatically when some function is fired. i cannot understand what is the problem. looked hours to other pages and there is no differences between them or i am missing something? What it chould be the problem? please help!

ok i found where is the problem a few seconds ago. i have the following code which returns me to the root when 'detailsview' is empty. but actually it is not empty.

```
  protected void DetailsView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DetailsView1.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            getRatings();
            getPhotos();
            incView();
        }
        else { Response.Redirect("/", true); }
    }
```

and this is my 'detailsview' definiton in aspx page. i think the DetailsView is not empty when there is a definiton like this : DataKeyNames="product_id"

```
 <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="600px" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="product_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataProductDetails" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" OnPreRender="DetailsView1_PreRender" GridLines="None">
```

i removed the redirect command and now the problem is there is no selected item to make changes on my page. i am using selected value as parameter for many functionalities. so still there is need of help.

I figured now my all prerender methods is not working :s

Comment: Consider sharing the code of the events or the section of the code in the page where from it returns to the root.

Answer (score 0):

the selected values are null
so it is redirecting to root as shown in the code

omit the line `response.redirect`  from the code

Comment: i removed the redirect command and now the problem is there is no selected item to make changes on my page. i am using selected value as parameter for many functionalities. so still there is need of help.

I figured now my all prerender methods is not working :s